# Swift lazy var on immutable structs

Tags: swift, struct, lazy-evaluation

I'm working with structs that stores data and makes some cached operations on it e.g.:

```swift
struct Number {
  let value: Int
  lazy var square = pow(Double(value), 2)
  lazy var squareRoot = Double(value).squareRoot()
  lazy var factorial = (1...value).reduce(1, *)
}
```

It works OK unless the it's variable:

```swift
var number = Number(value: 9)
number.square // 81
number.squareRoot // 3
number.factorial // 362 880
```

Otherwise you get the following error if it's constant:

```swift
let number = Number(value: 9)
number.square // Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'number' is a 'let' constant
```

There are several popular solutions:

**1. Change 'let' to 'var' to make it mutable**

It works with local variables only and doesn't with func parameters because they are constants by default and it forces to make a copy inside:

```swift
func f(number: Number) {
  var n = number
  n.factorial
}
```

**2. Convert struct to class**

It's not an option in my case.

**3. Use additional properties to store cached results**

According to these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/a/32292456/979986 and https://oleb.net/blog/2015/12/lazy-properties-in-structs-swift/ we can create a dedicated class instance to cache all our calculations:

For instance:

```swift
struct Number {
  let value: Int
  
  class Cache {
    var square: Double?
    var squareRoot: Double?
    var factorial: Int?
  }
  private let cache = Cache()
  ...
  var factorial: Int {
    guard let factorial = cache.factorial else {
      let res = (1...value).reduce(1, *)
      cache.factorial = res
      return res
    }
    return factorial
  }
}

let number = Number(value: 9)
number.factorial // 362 880
```

But this solution is redundant and inconvenient because I have to clone all my properties  in all my structs.

**Question**: Is there any other convenient approaches for most cases?

Comment: Using `inout` in your function fixes the first point.

Comment: `2. Convert struct to class It's not an option in my case.` Why is it not an option? If you own the code, why can't you change the `struct` to a `class`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor If `struct Number` is third party sdk I can't change its type, but I need to implement my lazy properties on it.

Comment: @iUrii how can you implement lazy properties on a type that you don't know? You can't add stored properties in an extension and if you don't own that type, the only way to add properties to it is via an extension. lazy properties must be stored properties, so I really don't see how can you add lazy properties to a type declared in a 3rd party SDK...

Answer (score 0):

It needs to store cached values outside your struct to make a common solution for immutable instances. Then you can access to this storage from your computed properties by a key than can be a location of code where this call appears:

```swift
class Lazy {
  private static var cache = [Int : Any]()
  
  static func `var`<T>(file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, column: Int = #column, f: () -> T) -> T {
    objc_sync_enter(self)
    defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }
    
    let key = "\(file):\(line):\(column)".hashValue
    guard let value = cache[key] as? T else {
      let value = f()
      cache[key] = value
      return value
    }
    return value
  }
}
```

Not it works like lazy properties on constant instance:

```swift
struct Number {
  let value: Int
  var square: Double { Lazy.var { pow(Double(value), 2) } }
  var squareRoot: Double { Lazy.var { Double(value).squareRoot() } }
  var factorial: Int { Lazy.var { (1...value).reduce(1, *) }}
}


let number = Number(value: 9)
number.square // 81
number.squareRoot // 3
number.factorial // 362 880
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the OP's #3 which is rejected in advance?

Comment: @matt The solution doesn't create additional instance variables on structs

Comment: This is a cool helper, but I give you my personal guarantee that the overhead of the lock, string allocation, hashing the string, and hashing the hash (inside the `cache[key]` call) will be _far_ longer than calculating the square, squareRoot or factorial on every use.

Comment: @Alexander This solution is not about performance it's about lazy initialisation of calculated properties. It's just a sample for the idea.

Comment: @iUrii I figured so, but I was just cautioning anyway. Have you considered using classes to model these value types? They can still be effectively immutable.

Comment: Also, you can speed up this implementation if you remove the double-hashing. Change your cache to just be `[String: Any]`, and dropping the explicit `.hashValue` call. Let `Dictionary` do the hashing for you, just once.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private and a public property for each "lazy" property and make the private one optional to know when to calculate a value or return the stored one

Example with `square`

```
struct Number {
    private var _square: Double?

    let value: Int
    var square: Double {
        get { _square ?? pow(Double(value), 2) }
        set { _square = newValue }
    }

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but requires to make a lot of private properties for every public ones

Comment: No only one per public property :)

Comment: You could also make the caching code autogenerated using a macro, then no need to manually declare any extra properties.